# zip function requires also a second list, how can it work with only one argument list

Tags: list, haskell, currying, partial-application

I started learning Haskell and found a nice exercise. It's the following:

```
grouping: Int -> [Student]->[(Team, Student)]
grouping teamNumber = zip ys
                      where ...
```

So, the exercise wants that i try to fill the rest. The function should do the following:
Example : `grouping 2 ['Mark','Hanna','Robert','Mike','Jimmy'] = [(1,'Mark'),(2,'Hanna'),(1,'Robert'),(2,'Mike'),(1,'Jimmy')]`.

So, we are building teams which consists of two Students, and the last Student 'Jimmy' has no teammates.

Then, I also look up what the predefined function `zip` does. It gets two list arguments and connects each element of the lists to a tuple to build a list of tuples.

My idea:
1) I try to build two functions "grab" and "infinite". They are looking as following:

```
grap :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
grab _ [] = []
grab n (x:xs) = if n <= 0 then [] else x : grab (n-1) xs  

infinite :: Num a => a -> [a]
infinite x = x : infinite(x+1)
```

So, what they do is: With `infinite` I want to create an infinite list. And `grap` should take `n` elements of that. Example `grap 2 (infinite 1) = [1,2]`.

I use these two in the first line of my *where*-declaration to fulfill the given function from above.
So, I have:

```
grouping: Int -> [Student]->[(Team, Student)]
grouping teamNumber = zip ys
                      where 
                      xs = grap teamNumber (infinite 1)
```

So, `xs` is now my first list of `zip`, especially the integer-list.

But now my question: `zip` as predefined function requires also a second list, especially the list of the names of the students, but in the given function they give zip only one argument, namely the `ys` as a list. How can I understand that?

Comment: in your `grouping`, you've omitted `ys = cycle xs`. Also, [`infinite` == `enumFrom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFrom), `infinite 1` == `[1..]`, [`grab` == `take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take), `take n [1..]` == `[1..n]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Type of `grouping teamNumber`

Look carefully at the type of `grouping :: Int -> [Student]->[(Team, Student)]`, and the arguments that are being declared for its declaration

```
grouping :: Int        -> [Student]->[(Team, Student)]
grouping    teamNumber =  ...
```

What is the return type (the type on the right-hand side of the equals sign) if `grouping` is provided with all the arguments listed on the left-hand side of the equals sign?

#### Answer

The type on the right-hand side of the equals sign is `[Student]->[(Team, Student)]`. In Haskell, a function that takes two arguments and returns a result can be equivalently seen or defined as a function that takes the first argument and returns a (function that takes the second argument and returns the result). So we could say, for example, that the expression

```
grouping 3 :: [Student]->[(Team, Student)]
```

`(grouping 3)` is a function that takes a list of students and returns a list of those students, labeled in 3 groups. Presumably, if `(grouping 3)` were applied to the list of students from your example, we would have

```
(grouping 3) [   'Mark' ,   'Hanna' ,   'Robert' ,   'Mike' ,   'Jimmy' ] =
             [(1,'Mark'),(2,'Hanna'),(3,'Robert'),(1,'Mike'),(2,'Jimmy')]
```

#### Type of `zip ys`

What does currying have to do with the following type and expression?

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
zip    ys
```

What would the type of `zip ys` be if, for example, `ys :: [Bool]`?

What does this have to do with your question?

When you consider this together with the type of `grouping teamNumber`, how does this tell you what the type of `ys` needs to be in your exercise?

#### Putting it all together

From the exercise code (ignoring the types and the `where` clause) we have:

```
grouping teamNumber = zip ys
```

Two things can only be `=` in Haskell if their types will unify. In this case, the type of `grouping teamNumber` must unify with the type of `zip ys`.

From the first part, we know that the type of `grouping teamNumber` is `[Student]->[(Team,Student)]`.

From the second part, we know that `zip ys` has the type `[b] -> [(a, b)]`, where `a` is a type such that `ys` has the type `[a]`.

Therefore, we know that (`~` is type equality in Haskell)

```
[Student]->[(Team,Student)] ~ [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

These will unify if we substitute the following for the type variables `b` and `a`

```
b ~ Student
a ~ Team
```

Now, we know the type of `ys` is `[a]`, which, if we make the same substitution, is `[Team]`.

Therefore, the types will be correct if `ys :: [Team]`.

#### Conclusion

If you can provide a `ys :: [Team]`, you can produce a function from students to students tagged with their team (`[Student]->[(Team,Student)]`) by passing the `ys` as the first argument to `zip`. Such a function is exactly what `grouping` needs to return when it has been applied to the single argument, `teamNumber :: Int`.

Comment: The type on the right-hand side of the equals sign must be ([Student], [(Team, Student)]), right ?

Comment: No, it's not a tuple containing both a list of Student and a list of tuple of Teams and Students. It's a function that takes a list of Students and returns a list of tuples of Teams and Students. `[Student]->[(Team, Student)]`. In Haskell, a function that takes two arguments and returns a result can be equivalently seen or defined as a function that takes the first argument and returns a (function that takes the second argument and returns the result). Aside: this is called "currying" and is named after Haskell Curry.

Comment: To answer your first question, i can say that the type of zip ys must be [b] -> [(Bool, b)]. But for the others I mus think about it

Comment: Does `[b] -> [(Bool, b)]` look like something else you need? Perhaps if you tried something else in the place of `Bool`?

Comment: i think, i should read some further information about currying before Im going on, because at the moment Im extremely confused.

Comment: Cirdec, dfeuer and Will Ness. thank you for your explanations. It helps me a lot to understand the exercise. I think, now i am ready to solve the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Currying can be a bit confusing when you first encounter it. Here's the deal, pretty much (there are some technicalities I'm going to ignore).

The basic concept is this: in Haskell, every function takes just one argument. If you want to simulate a function that takes two arguments, there are two ways to do this:

#### Tuples

You can write a function that takes a tuple. This is the conventional approach in Standard ML, but is typically only used in Haskell in cases where it is very particularly the most sensible thing to do:

```
distanceFromOrigin :: (Double, Double) -> Double
distanceFromOrigin (x, y) = sqrt (x^2 + y^2)
```

#### Currying

You can write a curried function. The concept behind currying is that when you apply a function to an argument you can get another function back that takes a second argument. I'll write this out very explicitly to begin with, using lambda notation:

```
product :: Double -> (Double -> Double)
product x = \y -> x * y
```

Suppose I start with `(product 3) 4`. I can reduce `(product 3)` first to get

```
(\y -> 3 * y) 4
```

Then I can finish off the job, getting 12.

Haskell offers a bit of syntax to help with this sort of thing. First off, it lets me write

```
product x y = x * y
```

to mean

```
product x = \y -> x * y
```

Secondly, it makes function application left-associative, so I can write `product 3 4` to mean `(product 3) 4`.

Finally, it makes the `->` type constructor right-associative, so I can write `product :: Double -> Double -> Double` instead of `product :: Double -> (Double -> Double)`.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, the following is equivalent:

```
f = (\x      y -> ..x..y..  )
f = (\x -> (\y -> ..x..y.. ))  -- this equivalence is known as "currying"
f     x =  (\y -> ..x..y.. )   -- partially applying f with x gives (\y->...)
f     x      y =  ..x..y..
```

(`(\x -> ...)` is of course Haskell's notation for anonymous, so called "*lambda*" functions (`\` being a reminder for the Greek letter `λ`.)

In Haskell, functions are just like other values, so there's no special syntax for function calls, or "function pointers" etc.. As for the types, the above naturally entails

```
f ::  a ->   b ->   t
f     x ::   b ->   t  -- the result of calling f w/ x (of type a) has type b->t
f     x      y ::   t  -- when f :: a->b->t, x :: a, y :: b, then f x y :: t
```

Stare at it for a moment.

So that's that about currying. Function calls are denoted just by juxtaposition in Haskell, and so it associates to the left (`f x y` is really `((f x) y)`). And because Haskell definitions are automatically *curried*, the arrows in types associate to the right (`a->b->c` is really `a->(b->c)`).