# Parsing embedded JSON with Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm trying to parse embedded JSON of the form

```
{
  "foo":"bar",
  "baz":"\{\"somekey\":\"someval\"\}"
}
```

with Aeson in Haskell. Here are my types:

```
data BaseType = BaseType { foo :: String, baz :: EmbeddedType } deriving(Show)

instance FromJSON BaseType where
  parseJSON = withObject "BaseType" $ \o -> do
    foo <- o .: "foo"
    baz <- o .: "baz"
    return $ BaseType { foo=foo, baz=baz }

data EmbeddedType = EmbeddedType { somekey :: String }

instance FromJSON EmbeddedType where
  parseJSON = withObject "EmbeddedType" $ \o -> do
    somekey <- o .: "somekey"
    return $ EmbeddedType {somekey=somekey}
```

Obviously, the `FromJSON` instance for `BaseType` doesn't work, since it sees it as a `Value String` instead of as more JSON for it to parse. I tried to find a way to use `decodeEither` in my `FromJSON BaseType` instance, but that required that I do some black magic to convert from `String` to `ByteString`, and I feel like there must be a neater way, possibly related to `withEmbeddedJSON`.

How can I make this work correctly?

Comment: Isn't this something that can be addressed with the standard `DeriveGeneric` mechanism of Aeson?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'm not sure what that means and google isn't spitting out anything useful for "DeriveGeneric Aeson". Would you mind explaining or linking me somewhere?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson.html

Comment: @MarkSeemann I don't think this solves my issue. It still gives a "got String expected EmbeddedType" error.

Comment: That's not something that is addressed by aeson's deriving stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it would be something like this (untested):

```
instance FromJSON BaseType where
  parseJSON = withObject "BaseType" $ \o -> do
    foo <- o .: "foo"
    bazText <- o .: "baz"
    baz <- withEmbeddedJSON "EmbeddedType" parseJSON (String bazText)
    return $ BaseType { foo=foo, baz=baz }
```

Or you could consider moving the call to `withEmbeddedJSON` into the `EmbeddedType` instance; then `o .: "baz"` should Just Work in the `BaseType` instance, at the cost of no longer having a handle onto a parser that just does `EmbeddedType` parsing without de-stringifying:

```
instance FromJSON BaseType where
  parseJSON = withObject "BaseType" $ \o -> do
    foo <- o .: "foo"
    baz <- o .: "baz"
    return $ BaseType { foo=foo, baz=baz }

instance FromJSON EmbeddedType where
  parseJSON = withEmbeddedJSON "EmbeddedType" . withObject "EmbeddedType" $ \o -> do
    somekey <- o .: "somekey"
    return $ EmbeddedType {somekey=somekey}
```

Comment: you could do `baz_ <- o .: "baz"` and give `baz_` type `Text` (aeson does decoding anyway). That would save the `case HM.lookup ....`.

Comment: I think you'll have to make an explicit call to `decode` in any case. (`parseJSON` still requires you to get a `Value` from somewhere)

Comment: @Li-yaoXia `withEmbeddedJSON` calls `decode` for you (well, `eitherDecode`, anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your help, and the code works, but would you mind helping me out a bit by explaining a couple things? I'm kinda new to Haskell, and I don't understand 1) how you're composing `withEmbeddedJSON` with `withObject`, 2) Your use of the `String` type constructor, and 3) How passing `parseJSON` into `withEmbeddedJSON` does what we want it to.

Comment: @thesecretmaster For (1) you might like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53725329/791604); for (2) I looked at the source of `withEmbeddedJSON` to see what it expected as input; for (3) type inference selects `parseJSON :: Value -> Parser EmbeddedType`, so it dispatches to your other instance for parsing the embedded JSON.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you very much!